# What ought to be the behavior of a union generic type, such as Array<A | B>?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I would expect a parameter types `Array<A | B>` to accept both `Array<A>` and `Array<B>`. But this does not appear so, why?

```
export type A = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  legacyId?: number;
};

export type B = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
};

export type AOrB = A | B;

function toB(items: Array<B>): Array<B> {
    return items
        .reduce((acc, item) => {
            if (typeof item.id === 'number') {
                const b = ((item:any):B);
                return [...acc, b];
            } else if (typeof item.id === 'string') {
                const a = ((item:any):A);
                return a.legacyId ? [...acc, {
                    id: a.legacyId,
                    title: a.name,
                }] : acc;
            }
            return acc;
        }, []);
}

function onUpdateItem(items: Array<B>) { 
  //...
}

function updateItem(items: Array<A>) {
    onUpdateItem(toB(items));
}
```

[Try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCcC8cDeAoOOASwBMAuOAZxiiIDsBzAbgLjoEMBbYC62xloQA2wBuwDGiAJIkA-BToBXTgCNgUFgF8WeUJFgJkqAEJZcrUguVqNrGERgjeNeszza8u8NHhIU6AHkoU2wMAB84Yx0AM0U6cXsIOgQIYwAKB2BOSgo0KCh2RAAeYwA+AEpc-MKS0vMASChgGEUoZMzsvHr6gDomkkVxYDS0iXEAGmIYLPKsOvxu+qJouDS-YAgVjp7SLExsAHIlVXUD2fxCS6vrwnEk6jgVMxGOsnY6RErjcpZFxubWskANo9UFjSYqAC6v26mjgwCElFQy1W602UyyOxIe0OfFcZ3MNyJcHqdzoD3Yzwy004bw+lTQPy6iyaLTacHYPREYkkMjgsjgILB4gmDT+lg5XNEEmkJHGzMW9kcPElHG48r+mkhcAoYxh9U0CtZgI5IphmkmQMhTMNeFi8USySSAFUwCR2NMpDTqVkcuhqsUyuc4KwAPSh0E9dyee0JIhJOCKN0e4BerI+7JVArFNAVBou5Oe70wVIZyjlG1AA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array<A | B>` means an array that can hold `A`s or `B`s.

`Array<A>` is not `Array<A | B>`, since it cannot hold `B`s (what would happen if you put a `B` in it?).

This is called invariance.

Comment: So an array of `A`s does not satisfy `Array<A | B>`?

Comment: @WillM: It depends on the compile-time type of the array itself; not its contents.

Comment: So, how can you solve this issue in which a return an be Array<A> or Array<B> but one doesn't know?

Comment: Thanks!! Offhand, if I don't know the full object being returned, is this ok to do: Array<Object> <--- "Object" being some arbitrary I don't know all the keys..